# Cannot parse a date

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I'm trying to parse this date: `1 January 2018` with `ParseExact`:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(context.MatchDate, "d MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("it-IT")).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

but I get this error:

> String not recognized as valid DateTime

I know that this question was already posted, but isn't the format correct?

Comment: The problem is that you are asking the Italian CultureInfo to understand a month written in english. You have your answer below.

Comment: The date is not recognized in the Culture it-IT.  So use InveriantCulture like Soner suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

January is *not* Italian. First month name is "[gennaio](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gennaio)" in italian.

You need to use english-based culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) to parse this english month name.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("1 January 2018", 
                               "d MMMM yyyy",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

From [The "MMMM" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-mmmm-custom-format-specifier);

> The "MMMM" custom format specifier represents the full name of the
>   month. **The localized name of the month is retrieved from the
>   `DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames` property of the current or specified
>   culture**.

Comment: I know, I need to translate the date in italian, in my code I added "it-It" as Culture, maybe you mean that I need to specify an InvariantCulture if the date is english? Thanks for the answer and happy new year!!!

Comment: @MrFantastic Yes, if you wanna parse english-based month, day etc names, you _have to_ specify english based cultures like `InvariantCulture`. There is no way to parse other than that. Do **not** go into tranlation process. You don't need it. Just use proper culture and you are fine. Happy new year you too!